# ParseJson data from array located in another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

Hello I'm trying to Parse `parseJson` data from an array. My problem is that I do not know how to access my response, because it is an array located in another array.

This is my response:

```
{
    "finalResult": [
        [
            {
            "Id":2,"latitude":"49.993820099043","longitude":"14.660662520439","usrId":2,"timeCreated":"2016-08-06 18:31:32"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
            "Id":3,"latitude":"49.993900553360","longitude":"14.660832398337","usrId":2,"timeCreated":"2016-08-06 18:29:37"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is part of code I need help with:

```
if let parseJson = json {

    if let events = parseJson["finalResult"] as? [AnyObject] {

        for event in events  {

            for single in (event as? [AnyObject])! {
                let Id = single["Id"] as! String
                let latitude = single["latitude"] as! String
                let longitude = single["longitude"] as! String
                let usrId = single["usrId"] as! String

                print(id)
                print(latitude)
                print(longitude)
                print(usrId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for event in events  {
    if let customObjects = event as? [AnyObject] {
        for customObject in customObjects {
            let Id = customObject["Id"] as! String
            let latitude = customObject["latitude"] as! String
            let longitude = customObject["longitude"] as! String
            let usrId = customObject["usrId"] as! String

            print(id)
            print(latitude)
            print(longitude)
            print(usrId)
        }
    }
}
```